# My nativescript android app crashing on startup in device?

Tags: android, nativescript

I am working on nativescript android app but it is crashing on device after flashscreen below is the error:

D/AccessibilityManager(25799):  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
    D/AccessibilityManager(25799):  at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1197)
    D/AccessibilityManager(25799):  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1061)
    D/AccessibilityManager(25799):  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1047)
    D/AccessibilityManager(25799):  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1028)
    D/AccessibilityManager(25799):  at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1018)

Comment: To provide more detailed error log run your application with 'tns run android --log trace'

Comment: i did that butit is not showing anything after or before this

Comment: Try doing: `adb logcat -c` then `adb logcat` and start the app.

Comment: { stdout: '', stderr: '', exitCode: 0 }
spawn: F:\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb "-s" "192.168.176.101:5555" "shell" "am" "force-stop" "com.plcpl.farmmate"
Result when throw error is false:

Comment: You must have misunderstood what I wanted.  Stop the app on the device, and clear it out of the running applications.  Then type `adb logcat -c` then `adb logcat` and leave it running...  Then start the app on the device using the icon on the device.    Once it crashes then copy the log...  The 6 lines you put above is only a small part of the log,   `adb logcat` will give you the full log...